# Is there a way to make a progressive REGEX string replacement?

Tags: regex

I'm using REGEX to find strings within specific parameters, for example:

```
<p>*(.+?)</p>
```

I would like each instance found to be replaced with a progressively increasing letter of the alphabet. So the first instance becomes `<p>A</p>`, the second becomes `<p>B</p>`, then `<p>C</p>`, etc. through the end of the document. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Javascript for this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The document is in HTML. I'm using an ebook software called Sigil which has a REGEX find/replace feature.

Comment: `>*`? *Really??* You want it to match 0 to many `>` characters? E.g. `<pA</p>`, `<p>A</p>`, `<p>>A</p>`, `<p>>>A</p>`, ...

Comment: sounds like a job for an actual programming language, preferably with an html parser unless the html is extremely restrictive and always near constant. Not a job for regex

Comment: https://textpad.com/products/textpad/features supports `\i` as regex replacement for an auto incremented number - so far the only product where I've seen such a thing and somewhat the closest to what OP wants without programming it himself.

Comment: No, it is not possible with regex.